# Webpack unable to load nested dependencies

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

For some reason when I run webpack, the compiler is unable to load my app.module from within main.ts. My application not including webpack can find all the modules correctly but when using Webpack it's unable to do so.

My webpack.config

```
      var webpack = require("webpack");
      var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

      module.exports= {
     entry: {
         'vendor': './vendor.ts',
         'polyfills' : './polyfills.ts',
         'app': './main.ts'
     },
     output:
     {
         path: './dist',
         filename: '[name].bundle.js',
     },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ]
 }
```

However running this I get the error

`./main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module' in 'C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\samples.solution\AngularCore\src'
 @ ./main.ts 2:0-41
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./main.ts`

I'm pretty lost at this point. I think it's a path issue but I'm not sure how to fix it to get Angular 2 bootstrapped and working.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `./app.module.ts`? Webpack doesn't automatically resolve `.ts`, unless configured.

Comment: Even though ./app.module.ts is dependent on Main.ts. I thought putting that in a webpack would automatically pull it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. After creating an app using Angular-Cli, inside the project I ran `ng eject` and it creates the webpack.confgiure.js and it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a couple of things are going on here.

First you aren't specifying your extensions.  See here: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#resolveextensions

Second, webpack can't compile typescript files so you're going to need to use a loader like awesome-typescript-loader. 
https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader